# How to eat MDIChild Minimize messages

Tags: winapi, vb6, windows-messages

I have some code which intercepts and eats WM_ExitSizeMove messages because I want to prevent users from maximizing MDIChild forms. I would also like to prevent them from minimizing MDIChild forms too but I can't figure out which message to intercept, does anyone know?

Comment: It is WM_SYSCOMMAND for both.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do is a lot easier than you're making it.  Just change the WindowState property on the MDIChild forms to FixedSingle.  That will prevent any resizing of the form, and will also get rid of the max and min buttons.

If you want resizing without Maximizing or Minimizing, you do have to go through the API.  You can also use EnumChildWindows to get rid of the max and min buttons.